# Is PFS recommended by the NCSC in the PRIME profile for IPsec

Tags: vpn, ipsec

Guidance on the PRIME profile for IPsec (https://www.ncsc.gov.uk/guidance/using-ipsec-protect-data) does not explicitly mention the use of PFS.

Is there a recommendation for its use in the Prime profile I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

The article provides basic principles for VPN and network design, and then gives fixed sets of encryption options without further explaining what their features are. Both *PRIME* (IKEv2) and *foundation* (IKEv1) profiles seem to use *Diffie-Hellman Group*s for deriving key material, providing *perfect forward secrecy* PFS. Explaining this or the other choices made is probably just beyond the scope of the guide.